# Phrase grammar, curae or curo

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, grammar-choice, new-latin

I have a phrase and I'm concerned with grammar. Which one would be more proper?

> et ego non curae

or

> et ego non curo

Phrase meaning would be "I don't care."

Comment: I removed your "gloss" on "I don't care" since it didn't really add anything to your translation request. If you are looking for something specifically vulgar, you should specify that in the question.

Comment: @brianpck Instead of the edit, perhaps a request for clarification should have been in order?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Feel free to roll back: I have no problem with a vulgar translation request *per se*, but the use of "like in" implied an example, which in this case was totally unnecessary. If it was the other way around I would have interpreted it differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way of saying "I care for X" in Latin is:

> X (nominative) mihi est curae.

or

> De X (ablative) mihi est curae.

This is a so-called *double dative* construction, and literally means "X is a concern to me" or "It is a concern to me about X." The proper way of saying "I don't care [about that]" is thus:

> **Mihi non est curae** [de hoc].

Here are some other options, mostly from my favorite Latin playwright. My translations are literal, but you could easily use some version of "don't care" instead:

> **Ista non curo.** (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum* 13.23.3.9)
>   *I don't care about these things.*
>
> **Istuc quidem edepol nihil est.** (Plautus, *Miles Gloriosus* 1.1)
>   *That is absolutely nothing.*
>
> **Tu [hoc] hau magni péndis.** (Plautus, *Pseudolus* 1.1)
>   *You really don't think that is worth much.*
>
> **Quod dixi flocci existumat.** (Plautus, *Mostellaria* 1.1)
>   *He doesn't give a straw for what I said.*

Depending on the context, the following can also be a way of "not caring":

> **Nugas blatis / garris** (Plautus, *Curculio* 3.1, 5.1)
>   *You're spewing nonsense.*
>
> **Quin tu is in malam crucem?** (Plautus, *Curculio* 5.2)
>   *Why don't you go to hell?* (lit. "a bad cross")

Comment: Ista non curo seems adequate for my purpose :) thank you.

Comment: Next you should get together all phrases like the last ones but in Greek, e.g. ἐς κόρακας!

Answer (score 6):

A great little phrase used was *flocci non facio*, rendered by the Victorians as "I care not a straw for" but really means something closer to "I don't give a rat's ass." It was used by both Cicero (*Att*. 13.50.3) as well as Plautus (all over the place) and Terence (*Eun*. 3.1.21), so it's clearly a common and idiomatic phrase.

Comment: *floccus* means a lock / flock: why do you think a "rat's ass" is a closer rendition than "straw"? The phrase never struck me as particularly crass.

Comment: I didn't say it literally meant that, but that's the feeling behind it. Yes, perhaps "rat's ass" is a bit too crude, but it's the closer in sentiment, whereas "I care not a lock of" is absolutely meaningless in English. Even phrases like "I don't care one whit for" are too lofty for it.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference in your phrases is that "curae" is a noun and "curo" is a verb. Therefore, *et ego non curae* is not exactly a complete phrase because there is no verb.
*et ego non curo* is correct and means "I don't care", but you could also say *et ego non curam do*, which means "I don't give a care". It just depends whether you want to use a verb or noun to translate care.
Additionally, you don't directly have to include *ego* because that is indicated by the verb ending.